# Accidentally enabled some error checking, cannot undo

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am assigning an Error object to a variable, and adding some custom properties to it.

VS Code error checking highlighted the new property, saying its not part of the Error object, which is true, but it works anyway.

So I clicked "quick fix" and accidenntally clicked an option, but no idea what it was.

The error highlighting has gone, but now if i add other custom properties, they all get checked against being the same type as the first custom property.

eg first custom property was a number, if i add a string, it now highlights that saying its not of type number.

what setting did i enable, and how do i disable it?

Comment: Well it was, especialy as I could't remember what I clicked. Feel better now?

Answer (score 1):

If I declare a `Error.mycustom = 1` VS Code offers two fixes:

- Declare property 'custom'
- Add index signature for property 'custom'

Both seem to modify the `ErrorConstructor` interface. The first option simply adds a `mycustom: number` to it, while the second one adds `[x: string]: number`. To find the modification, right click on `Error` an select "Go to Definition". Then you simply have to look for the `ErrorConstructor` interface in that file (typically directly below the definition of `Error`) and remove the custom declaration.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I couldn't find it at first, as I was looking in the global TS definition, but I found it hidden away in `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts`